# Padding between relative and absolute positions

Tags: css, width, css-position, padding, percentage

I am changing the positioning of children elements from relative to absolute.

The children elements have a width which is a percentage of the parent's width. When I change the position from relative to absolute, the percentage now includes the parent's padding. In the demo hover the black div.

- How can I avoid the parent padding being included in the children's percentage?
- Why does it act differently in both position values?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h5mcvuo6/2/).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#parent {
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  height: 100vh;
  padding-right: 100px;
  background: pink;
  position: relative;
}

.children {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  float: left;
}
.children:nth-child(2) {
  background: grey;
}

#parent:hover .children {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#parent:hover .children:nth-child(2) {
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">

  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Why do you want to change the position types? what is you expect result?

Comment: This is a simplified case of the exact issue. The real case is a grid where elements are position:relative; float:left; . Once the javascript is loaded it assigns the top/left exact value and position:absolute; so when the user interacts in some way with the site, the top/left values are changed and can be transitioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an element is set to `position:absolute`, its containing box is the parent's padding box (the box around the padding). The result in your example is correct.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h5mcvuo6/1/)**

You can probably do this to get the result you want, and `width:calc(100% - 100px)` on the parent doesn't seem to be necessary in your example.

```
#children:hover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 100px; /* the same value as parent's right padding */
  width: auto; /* reset to default, depending on 'left' and 'right' values */
}
```

**EDIT**

OP actually has two absolute divs inside, using `calc()` can help.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h5mcvuo6/3/)**

```
#parent:hover .children {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: calc(50% - 50px);
}
#parent:hover .children:nth-child(2) {
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
}
```

But, the **easiest way** would be adding an additional container to the parent, and set the padding and background on it, rest of style unchanged.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h5mcvuo6/4/)**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="parent">
    <div class="children"></div>
    <div class="children"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
#container {
  padding-right: 100px;
  background: pink;
}
#parent {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The line you comment comes from the original, which had a margin, but you are right. The solution works for this case, truth is I actually have two children like in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h5mcvuo6/2/). Would there be a chance of applying something similar?

Comment: I'm using some `calc()` in https://jsfiddle.net/h5mcvuo6/3/ If you can work on the parent element, that would make things easier, i.e. add another container.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works, and probably is the easiest/best way. It is almost what @johnchinjew was proposing.

Comment: I would add another container, e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/h5mcvuo6/4/ to make it easy, no crazy calcs :)

Comment: This last proposal is definitely the best way to go. Things were getting too complex and adding an extra container simplifies things. Could you please update the answer with this solution so I can accept it? Thanks!

Comment: OK, updated, I didn't see the other answer (was busy editing), but I think my answer is still better for solving your original question.

Answer (score 1):

This is because an absolutely positioned element is taken out of it's parent's flow.

It therefore no longer recognizes the padding of the parent.

It simply relates itself to the boundary of whatever ancestor has a position relative or position absolute. The boundary's 0,0 point is the point just inside the border and stretches horizontally to the right boundary just before any right-hand border.

You will therefore have to define similar padding to the absolutely positioned element that you did on its parent.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed description and reasoning behind.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution: Add a width property to the #children on hover.

```
#children:hover {
    width: calc(100% - 100px) /* <-- Add this */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a simplified example, however it could work but lets see if someone comes with other way, or some property I am missing.